# Turn off QuickTime 'start page'

Tags: quicktime, advertisements

When I start Apple QuickTime (regular non-pro version), it comes up with this page of content including "Hot Picks", "Quick Hits" and other advertising, which I assume it is getting from the internet.

How do I turn this off? I just want it to open the blank player, ready for me to play a file etc and not connect to the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn off the **Content Guide** in the Quicktime Player preferences.

Windows options

```
Edit-> Preferences-> Player Preferences
```

Turn off "**Show Content Guide at startup**"

Click 'OK'

No more content guide at startup.

I don't remember where the Mac preference is but you should just have to turn off the "**Content Guide**" in the player preferences.

Comment: Thanks! I already looked through the preferences and didn't spot that one. I guess I didn't know what the startup screen was called.